# PingFederate use ognl expression to get security group

Tags: active-directory, ognl, pingfederate

I'm trying to know if a user in AD it's on a specific security group, I tried using the example in https://www.pingidentity.com/en/blog/2013/07/25/looping_in_ognl.html and change it to fit my needs

```
#admin="",
#groups = #this.get("ds.LDAP.memberOf")!=null?#this.get("ds.LDAP.memberOf").getValues() : {},
#i= 0,
#groups.{
#group = new javax.naming.ldap.LdapName(#groups[#i]),  
    #cn = #group.getRdn(#group.size() - 1).getValue().toString(),  
    #admin=#cn.equals("Managers")?true:"",  
    #i = #i + 1 },  
#admin=(#admin!="")?true:""
```

But my script only return true when the CN I 'm searching i'ts the first in the list, otherwise it returns empty.
I checked and the length of the groups array it's only one item containing all the groups
but the Active Directory is returning all the memberOf in one line like CN=Managers,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com, CN=Finance,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com, CN=Employees,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#memberOf=#this.get("ds.LDAP.memberOf").toString(),#idx=#memberOf.indexOf("GROUPNAME"), #result = #idx >= 0 ? "TRUE": "FALSE"
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, that did the trick the only thing I added was the full name of the security group like CN=Managers,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com instead of just Managers